# How do I call Axios on prop change in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

On the change of the value `id`, I would like to make a JSON call via Axios and update necessary parts of the page. How do I do that? Currently, I have `mounted` and `activated` and they do not seem to be working...

Code:

```
const Home = { 
    template: `

    <div class="user">
        <h2>user {{ id }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ info }}</h2>
        bet
    </div>

    `,
    props: {
        id: {
            type:    String,
            default: 'N/A'
        }
    },
    data () {
        return {
          info: null
        }
      },
    activated () {
        axios
          .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json', 
          { params: { id: id }}
          )
          .then(response => (this.info = response))
      }, 

      mounted() {
        axios
          .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
          .then(response => (this.info = 'response'))
      } 
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `id` prop change by using [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property):

```
watch: {
  id: function(newId) {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json',
           { params: { id: newId }}
      )
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
}
```

---

Here is a little demo based on the code that you shared that shows how `watch` reacts to `id` prop change. `Wrapper` component below is solely for demonstration purpose as something that triggers `id` value change.

```js
const Home = {
  template: `

    <div class="user">
        <h2>user {{ id }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ info }}</h2>
        bet
    </div>

    `,
  props: {
    id: {
      default: 'N/A'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = 'response'))
  },
  watch: {
    id: function(newId) {
      console.log(`watch triggered, value of id is: ${newId}`);
      axios
        .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json',
          { params: { id: newId }}
        )
        .then(response => (this.info = response))
    }
  }
}

const Wrapper = {
  template: '<div><home :id="id" /></div>',
  components: { Home },
  data() {
     return {
        id: 0
     }
  },
  mounted() {
     const limit = 5;
     const loop = (nextId) => setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(`#${nextId} loop iteration`);
       if (nextId < limit) {
          this.id = nextId;
          loop(nextId + 1);
       }
     }, 3000);
     loop(this.id);
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Wrapper }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js" ></script>
<div id="app">
<wrapper />
</div>
```

Comment: Where would that go? Sorry I am new to Vue :') @antonku

Comment: @BryanSanders No problem :) I have update the answer

Comment: I am not seeing it update when my `{{ id }}` is being updated. I more so want to be able to go from 'product/foo' to '/product/facts' and call that axios. What does that? I apologize again haha!

Comment: I see, can you please check if `watch` callback is being called at all when `id` prop is changed?

Comment: @BryanSanders I have updated the answer with the demo of using `watch` with your component. Hopefully it will be of some help.