# vuejs - cached data used with different url

Tags: vue.js

I have built a profile vue page but I realized that when I change URL parameter it does not load new user but displays the first user. I load data in `created` which is probably the cause. How can I tell the page that it has a different parameter and it shall reload?

router.js

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/profile/:id',
      name: 'user-profile',
      component: () => import('./views/Profile.vue'),
      props: true,
    },
```

Profile.vue

```
async created() {
  const response = await this.$store.dispatch('GET_USER_PROFILE_BY_ID', { id: this.id });
  this.userProfile = response.data.data;
```

URLs:

- http://localhost:8080/profile/1dvklq9cnz
- http://localhost:8080/profile/1e0tcb2kn2

Comment: Are you using `keep-alive`?

Comment: I do not know this vue parameter. There is no occurrence in the source code

Comment: You can `watch` for `id` and then trigger the call. Here is the similar question [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162239/how-do-i-call-axios-on-prop-change-in-vue?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057473/vue-js-update-router-view/60058175#60058175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The created hook only gets executed when the component is actually created.  changing the url to load the same route, but with a different ID is a routeUpdate instead.

> Remember that params or query changes won't trigger enter/leave navigation guards. You can either watch the $route object to react to those changes, or use the beforeRouteUpdate in-component guard.
>   https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Abstract out the fetch & set that you have in your created hook.  Then, call it in both created() and beforeRouteUpdate().

```
{
methods: {
    async getProfile(id) {
        const response = await this.$store.dispatch('GET_USER_PROFILE_BY_ID', { id});
        this.userProfile = response.data.data;
    }
    created() { this.getProfile(this.id); },
    beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) { 
        const { params: {id} } = to;
        this.getProfile(id); 
        next(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that beforeRouteUpdate is called when I click on a different URL. But the page is not changed and URL remains unchanged as well. Nevertheless I know now where to start.

Comment: I forgot that the route guards require you to call `next` to continue on and have updated the example to show getting the ID from the next route.